# Display Images Inline via CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, position

I have three images that I want to display in a single row next to each other.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="client_logos">
<img style="display: inline; margin: 0 5px;" title="heartica_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/heartica_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" />
<img style="display: inline; margin: 0 5px;" title="mouseflow_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/mouseflow_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" />
<img style="display: inline; margin: 0 5px;" title="piiholo_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/piiholo_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" />
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#client_logos { display: inline-block; }
```

For some reason, it only displays two logos next to each other. Not sure what's wrong. Any ideas?

URL: http://rainleader.com/who-we-are/

See screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a line break `<br>` in-between the second and third images in your markup. Get rid of that, and it'll show inline.

Comment: When in doubt, open up your web inspector. :) Glad I could help.

Comment: No worries... I got side tracked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The code you have posted here and code on your site both are different. There is a break `<br>` after second image, so the third image into new line, remove this `<br>` and it will display correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Place this css in your page:

```
<style>
   #client_logos {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    }
  </style>
```

**Replace**

```
<p><img class="alignnone" style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="heartica_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/heartica_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" /><img class="alignnone" style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="mouseflow_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/mouseflow_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" /><img class="alignnone" style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="mouseflow_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/piiholo_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" /></p>
```

To

```
<div id="client_logos">
<img style="display: inline; margin: 0 5px;" title="heartica_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/heartica_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" />
<img style="display: inline; margin: 0 5px;" title="mouseflow_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/mouseflow_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" />
<img style="display: inline; margin: 0 5px;" title="piiholo_logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainleader/assets/piiholo_logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="50" />
</div>
```