# How do i space images out on the same <div class

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I only have basic knowledge (if that) of HTML because of an assignment. I'm trying to make 3 pictures on the same line but I need them to be spaced out from each other. I've got no javascript folder/document yet.  Also if possible could I make it so the image zooms in when the mouse hovers over it.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="products">
    <p><img src="images/shirt 1.png" style="width: 250px"></p>
    <p><img src="images/hoodie.jpg" style="width: 250px"></p>
    <p><img src="images/cap.png" width="268px" style="height 50px"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to write some css for that

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but we're not here to write code for you. Do some research, make an attempt yourself, and come back when you get stuck on something specific. See this page on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

on your `<div class="products" style="display:flex;">`

also see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: That has stretched the images out vertically

Comment: or you can do float:left for each image or try display:inline;.

Comment: few more tricks here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263186/display-images-inline-via-css

Answer (score 0):

```
.products{
    display: flex;
}

img{
  justify-content: center;
  margin:0 20px;
}
```

Here the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7xusu2r1/

Answer (score 0):

Joel, you don't need Javascript for what you're trying to achieve. What you need to use is CSS.

CSS is of course used for styling, transitions, animations, etc. Having the pictures be spaced from each other is styling and having it increase in size when hovered over is a transition (actually it's a transform).

Here's what I'm going to do. Since I don't know the EXACT effect that you are looking for, I will first provide you with code that works, explain the code, and then give you a link that may help you dive deeper into what I think you're looking to do.  Here goes...

**HTML**

```
<div class="products">
    <img src="images/shirt 1.png">
    <img src="images/hoodie.jpg">
    <img src="images/cap.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.products {
    width: 880px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    margin: auto;
}

img {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 20px;
}

img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

What is happening is this... (FIRST) Instead of having the styling written out in the HTML after each pic, I put it in the CSS file. I noticed that you gave one of the pics a different size. There are work-arounds for that, but I didn't have access to your pic files, so I used some of my own. You will have to use your judgement on the sizes.

(SECOND) In the CSS code I gave the "img" tags a cursor of "pointer", which will change your cursor to what people are used to seeing when something is clickable, and a "transform: scale" setting to change the size of the pic when hovered over.

And that's it for the big changes. The one other thing I did, for the sake of being organized and you seeing the changes more clearly was I gave the "product" div a width, a background color, and a margin of "auto" so that it would go to the center of the page. Those are things you don't have to do... I just did them to make the example look a little neater and clean.

There are things you can add to the transformation of the scale, like giving it a time to take to happen, which will make it more animated instead of more sudden looking, etc., but I think it would be better for you to understand what's going on before just throwing you a bunch of code to try and backwards engineer.

Speaking of better understanding, here is a link that I think may be useful:
[W3Schools CSS Page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

I would take a look at and learn all of those aspects of basic CSS and then check out the CSS3 section.

Hope that all helps!

Comment: One more thing!!!!  In the CSS code I gave, it is the "margin" that gives the pics the space you are looking for. Sorry I forgot to explain that... I just woke up!